# error: invalid operands to binary expression ('book' and 'const int') in find in c++

Tags: c++, stl, overloading

```
class book{
public:
   void setNameOfAuthor(string nameOfAuthor);
   string getNameOfAuthor();
   void setBookId(int bookid);
   int getBookId();
   bool operator==(const book& rhs)const;
   const int operator*()const;
private:
    string m_nameOfAuthor;
    int m_bookId;
};
```

```
class bms{
    private:
        vector<book> m_books;
    public:
        void addNewBook(book& booktoadd);
        void deleteBook();
        void displayBook();  
};
```

```
bool book::operator==(const book& rhs)const{
    return m_bookId == rhs.m_bookId;
}

const int book::operator*()const{
    return m_bookId;
}

void bms::deleteBook(){
    int booid;
    auto itr = find(m_books.begin(), m_books.end(), booid); ------>issue is here 
    if( itr != m_books.end()){
        m_books.erase(itr);
    }else{
        cout<<"book is not found!!"<<endl;
    }
}
```

```
im working on book management system project , trying to delete a book in find i get error as 
Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.3.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/algorithm:919:22: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('book' and 'const int')
```

```
 if (*__first == __value_)
```

so i tried overloading == operator and *operator but couldnt resolve my issue , not getting where im doing wrong

in find if i debug i think issue is

```
find(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last, const _Tp& __value_)
{
    for (; __first != __last; ++__first)
        if (*__first == __value_)-------------> issue seems to be hereis here 
            break;
    return __first;
}
```

as i overloaded == operator so comparasion should happen between int and int im not getting why comparsion is happening between book object and int. please help

Comment: If you want to find a book by it's id use `std::find_if` not `std::find`.

Comment: `__first` is not a `book`, `*__first` is.

Comment: Use [`std::find_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) with a suitable [lambda function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda).

Comment: ***Or*** create an overload of `==` that compares `int` with `book` (and `book` with an `int`, yes order matters). I''d rather recommend the `std::find_if` and lambda solution though.

Comment: On the other hand, considering your use-case perhaps [`std::remove_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) would be a better solution? But for that please read more about [the erase-remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom).

Comment: thank you so much for all the reply using find_if it works

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find a book by it's id, you can use `std::find_if` with a [lambda expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627098/what-is-a-lambda-expression-in-c11)

```
auto itr = find_if(
    m_books.begin(), 
    m_books.end(), 
    [=](const Book& b) { return b.getBookId() == booid; }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using an (uninitialized) `int` to search for a `book` but there is no `operator==` for comparing a `book` with an `int`.

You could define free operators for comparing a `book` with an `int` to solve the issue:

```cpp
bool operator==(const book& b, int id) { return b.getBookId() == id; }
bool operator==(int id, const book& b) { return b == id; }
bool operator!=(const book& b, int id) { return !(b.getBookId() == id); }
bool operator!=(int id, const book& b) { return b != id; }
```

---

Another option is to actually create a `book` with the `id` you want to search for:

```cpp
book bs;
bs.setBookId(booid); // note: booid must be initialized before this
auto itr = std::find(m_books.begin(), m_books.end(), bs);
```

---

A third option is to use `std::find_if` with a lambda as shown in [john's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76939766/7582247).

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment, for your use-case you should use [`std::remove_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) instead of any "find" function:

```
m_books.erase(std::remove_if(m_books.begin(), m_books.end(), [booid](Book const& b)
{
    return b.getBookId() == booid);
}), m_books.end());
```

The above will remove all books matching `booid` from the container `m_books`.

Note that we need to use [the *erase-remove idiom*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom) to both remove the elements and erase unused elements after the removal.